# Memory alignment (Using C specifically)

Tags: c, memory, struct

If you've got a struct within a struct, say:

```
struct {
    double a;
    struct {
        char *b[20];
        char c;
    }d;
}e;
```

will struct e need to start on a multiple of the size of struct d, or a multiple of the size of the largest member of d (char *b[20])?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's compiler- and settings-dependent.  In most cases will start at the first member's granularity, which in your case is `sizeof(char*)`.  Note, that it's not `sizeof(char*) * 20`, since it's an array and not a native type.  Also note that in your case, the `struct e` will always start at least at granularity of `sizeof(double)`, and therefore `struct d` will do too.

Comment: Depending on the platform, a double might not require `sizeof (double)` alignment.  See my answer.

Comment: @ughoavgfhw: you're right: missed the star.  fixed the answer

Answer (score 5):

The struct `e` will start at whatever alignment is necessary for the members, and the struct as a whole, to be accessible.

That alignment will vary for different implementations.

We know that the alignment for `e` will be *at least* as strict as the alignmentf for `double` *and* at least as strict as the alignment for `e.d` -- and the alignment of `e.d` will be at least as strict as the alignment for its members.

Contrary to the other answers, the alignment of a scalar type is not necessarily the same as its size.  For example, it's possible that `double` might be 8 bytes, but only require 4-byte alignment.  Aligning each scalar type (integer, floating-point, pointer) to its full size is fairly common, but it's not universal.

And note that the *optimal* alignment may be more strict than the *required* alignment.  On the x86, as I understand it, the CPU can access objects on any byte boundary -- but access to properly aligned objects is more efficient.  (On other CPUs, misaligned access may require software support.)  Compilers will typically align objects for maximum efficiency (but may provide non-standard extensions to save space).

But the alignment for a type cannot *exceed* its size.  For example, you can't have a 3-byte type that requires 4-byte alignment.  Arrays cannot have gaps between their elements.  (In such a case, the compiler would probably pad the type to 4 bytes; the padding would be part of the object, not inserted between objects.)

Comment: Very informative answer, however this is for a homework assignment, so I don't think my prof wants me to get too in-depth :)